# Как избавиться от пустого пространства внутри flex item?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

http://codepen.io/smellyshovel/pen/aNrgMK
Как видите, сейчас все нормально (chrome 50.0.2).
Но стоит сделать так...
http://codepen.io/smellyshovel/pen/BKeggj
...и у более коротких flash'ей появляются пустые места слева. Как избавиться от такого поведения?

```
<section class="fashbox">
  <div class="flash-notice">
    <span class="text">You have been signed up successfully
</span>
    <span class="close">
      X
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="flash-notice">
    <span class="text">You have been signed up successfully!</span>
    <span class="close">
      X
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="flash-alert">
    <span class="text">You have been signed up successfully!</span>
    <span class="close">
      X
    </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот этот момент был упущен из внимания: `flex-flow: column`.
На него не так действует `justify-content: flex-end`.

Поэтому, чтобы решить нюанс, нужно к флекс боксу (section.fashbox) нужно добавить align-items: flex-end/flex-start/center, тогда наши кнопки будут занимать ровно такое пространство, сколько они должны занимать будь они inline элементами.

Если `flex-direction: column` не указывать сторону *прижима* элементов, они по дефолту будут растягиваться по всей ширине блока.

**Или** нужным `.flash-` кнопкам задать align-self + сторона *прижима*.

Comment: Вот вам - спасибо большое. Я действительно не подумал о том, что если указал `flex-flow: column`, то `align-items: flex-end` теперь будет выравнивать как бы по-горизонтали. Теперь все работает как надо, но: меня смутили ваши дальнейшие слова "ровно такое пространство, которое они должны занимать, будь они инлайн-элементами". Мне теперь нужно указать каждому флешу `display: inline-flesh`? И еще. "Если в `flex-direction` не указывать сторону прижима..." Вы, вероятно, хотели скзать, "в `flex-flow`.

Comment: то есть `display: inline-flex`

Comment: И еще кое-что. Посмотрите, пожалуйста на этот скриншот (с мобильного). Чем можно объяснить то, что кнопка закрытия с каждой дополнительной строчкой текста сдвигается все правее и правее? http://imgur.com/w6r6KLF

Comment: 1. Мне теперь нужно указать каждому флешу display: inline-flex - нет, не нужно.
2. flex-direction: row/column, flex-flow: row/column wrap/nowrap. Т.е., в flex-flow можно указать сразу два параметра: направление и разрыв.
3. Посмотрите, пожалуйста на этот скриншот - нужна ссылка или код.

Comment: Пожалуйста: http://codepen.io/smellyshovel/pen/xVoWdL (прошу учесть, что нужно создать маленькую ширину (при перетягивании вы увидите, как крестик смещает в сторону)).